# how append an object to association relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails 4.1 application I need to add an object to an "AssociationRelation"

```
  def index
    employee = Employee.where(id_person: params[:id_person]).take
    receipts_t = employee.receipts.where(:consent => true) #gives 3 results 
    receipts_n = employee.receipts.where(:consent => nil).limit(1) #gives 1 result

    #I would need to add the null consent query result to the true consent results
    #something similar to this and the result is still an association relation
    @receipts = receipts_t + receipts_n

  end
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of solving this:

```
  def index
    employee_receipts = Employee.find_by(id_person: params[:id_person]).receipts
    receipts_t = employee_receipts.where(consent: true)
    receipts_n = employee_receipts.where(consent: nil).limit(1)

    @receipts = Receipt.where(id: receipts_t.ids + receipts_n.ids)
  end
```

Unfortunately `.or()` can't be used here because it's only available from Rails v5.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

you could do this way

```
receipts_t_ids = employee.receipts.where(:consent => true).pluck(:id)
receipts_n_ids = employee.receipts.where(:consent => nil).limit(1).pluck(:id)

@receipts = Receipt.where(id: receipts_t_ids + receipts_n_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid extra queries and keeping arrays in memory, you can use `or`

Like this:

```
def index
  employee_receipts = Employee.find_by(id_person: params[:id_person]).receipts

  @receipts =
    employee_receipts.where(consent: true).or(
      employee_receipts.where(consent: nil).limit(1)
    )
end
```